# Are there any tools like the Microsoft Azure Service Bus Explorer for monitoring Salesforce Platform Events?

Tags: event, platform-event, subscriber, event-monitoring, publish-subscribe

I'm looking for a good way to monitor the Platform Events being published by our org, so I can check that they are actually being published and have the expected content.

On Azure, I could use the Microsoft Azure Service Bus Explorer to peek at (or retrieve or add to) messages in a Queue or Topic.

Is there anything similar for the Salesforce Event Bus?

Comment: I have been reading about a lot of cool platform event monitoring implementations with Heroku. Might be something to look into, here is an example by Heroku https://github.com/heroku-examples/salesforce-streams-nodejs

Comment: @MaxGoldfarb, cheers for the suggestion. I'll need to take a closer look at this.  :-)

Comment: @MaxGoldfarb, Looked at it.... Unless I'm missing something, as-is, there is no support for monitoring custom events and  it does not tell me about the contents of the event.   BUT, I didn't know "Change Data Capture" which could actually be really useful for us.  Cheers again for this!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Labs came out with a decent, free package for this on the AppExchange:

**[Streaming Monitor](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYEEWUA5)**

The Lightning App lets you monitor streaming events: PushTopic events, generic events, standard and custom platform events, Change Data Capture events, and monitoring events.

I've found it to be pretty useful. It has a 4.5 star rating on 22 reviews. Salesforce has continued to support/update it (latest release on 7/27/22).

From the AppExchange listing:

> Features:
>
> - Subscribe to all streaming events (event types are automatically discovered)
> - Subscribe to and unsubscribe from specific streaming events with a user-friendly UI
> - Publish an event (generic events and platform events)
> - Register an event source (instructions and shortcuts)
>
> Analyze past event content with:
>
> - timeline or table view
> - dynamic filters
> - flexible replay options
>
> The app leverages the lightning-emp-api Lightning Web Component for
> streaming event subscriptions and D3.js to draw a dynamic event
> timeline.

Comment: Cheers for the response... I'm looking for something which can be used without access to any Salesforce Instance, but maybe this will do in a pinch if, for example, it might be used by some arbitrary person in a developer org....